# how to solve this program auto killed when running market subscription threads to insert data into mongodb?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, trading

system is centOS 7 on a vultr vps.
program is like vnpy that subscribe market data and save them in local database, in this case mongodb 4.0.1.
program writes in python 2.7.
when running the program for minutes, it will be auto killed by process.
checking the mongodb log:

```
2018-08-17T11:01:34.509+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:41042 #93 (1 connection now open)
2018-08-17T11:01:37.620+0200 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after freeMonitoring: 0, after globalLock: 0, after locks: 0, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 0, after network: 0, after opLatencies: 0, after opcounters: 0, after opcountersRepl: 0, after repl: 0, after security: 0, after storageEngine: 0, after tcmalloc: 225, after transactions: 260, after wiredTiger: 389, at end: 1253 }
2018-08-17T11:01:38.717+0200 I NETWORK  [conn93] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:41042 conn93: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }
2018-08-17T11:01:39.824+0200 I COMMAND  [conn93] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, client: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:239 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1792ms
2018-08-17T11:01:43.219+0200 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 95, after asserts: 353, after backgroundFlushing: 412, after connections: 474, after dur: 474, after extra_info: 474, after freeMonitoring: 474, after globalLock: 636, after locks: 701, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 814, after network: 930, after opLatencies: 1057, after opcounters: 1251, after opcountersRepl: 1314, after repl: 1409, after security: 1483, after storageEngine: 1580, after tcmalloc: 1647, after transactions: 1647, after wiredTiger: 1754, at end: 2390 }
2018-08-17T11:01:46.830+0200 I COMMAND  [conn93] command VnTrader_Log_Db.20180817 command: insert { insert: "20180817", ordered: true, $db: "VnTrader_Log_Db" } ninserted:1 keysInserted:1 numYields:0 reslen:60 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 3020ms
2018-08-17T11:01:48.613+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:41046 #94 (2 connections now open)
2018-08-17T11:01:49.545+0200 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 69, after backgroundFlushing: 69, after connections: 79, after dur: 79, after extra_info: 155, after freeMonitoring: 289, after globalLock: 351, after locks: 351, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 351, after network: 628, after opLatencies: 992, after opcounters: 1281, after opcountersRepl: 1305, after repl: 1305, after security: 1402, after storageEngine: 1619, after tcmalloc: 1851, after transactions: 1869, after wiredTiger: 2347, at end: 2914 }
2018-08-17T11:01:51.464+0200 I NETWORK  [conn94] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:41046 conn94: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }
2018-08-17T11:01:52.505+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:41048 #95 (3 connections now open)
2018-08-17T11:01:52.974+0200 I COMMAND  [conn94] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, client: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:239 locks:{} protocol:op_query 1269ms
2018-08-17T11:01:53.255+0200 I NETWORK  [conn93] end connection 127.0.0.1:41042 (2 connections now open)
2018-08-17T11:01:53.276+0200 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 242, after asserts: 662, after backgroundFlushing: 692, after connections: 802, after dur: 879, after extra_info: 1038, after freeMonitoring: 1235, after globalLock: 1522, after locks: 1577, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 1577, after network: 1577, after opLatencies: 1577, after opcounters: 1577, after opcountersRepl: 1577, after repl: 1577, after security: 1577, after storageEngine: 1605, after tcmalloc: 1605, after transactions: 1605, after wiredTiger: 1605, at end: 1605 }
2018-08-17T11:01:53.286+0200 I NETWORK  [conn95] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:41048 conn95: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core", architecture: "x86_64", version: "3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }
2018-08-17T11:01:53.296+0200 I NETWORK  [conn95] end connection 127.0.0.1:41048 (1 connection now open)
2018-08-17T11:01:53.296+0200 I NETWORK  [conn94] end connection 127.0.0.1:41046 (0 connections now open)
```

checking the system messages log, the messages below repeatedly appear:

```
Aug 17 11:53:25 vultr python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from read access on the file netstat.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that mongod should be allowed read access on the netstat file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'ftdc' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ftdc#012# semodule -i my-ftdc.pp#012
Aug 17 11:53:25 vultr setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from read access on the file snmp. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 78d2809a-7188-4cc7-a885-86a556908eb0
Aug 17 11:53:25 vultr python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from read access on the file snmp.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that mongod should be allowed read access on the snmp file by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'ftdc' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ftdc#012# semodule -i my-ftdc.pp#012
Aug 17 11:53:26 vultr setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from read access on the file netstat. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 78d2809a-7188-4cc7-a885-86a556908eb0
```

why does this happen and how can I avoid the auto kill?

Comment: Please do not add external screenshots of log output. Add the output directly to your question with an indentation of 4 spaces.

Comment: problem eddited. @mbuechmann , the error output of my program is just 'killed', I run it in shell

Comment: The messages contain suggestions on how you can fix the errors. Have you tried that?